# Как удалить дубликаты в цикле Python (спарсеные данные BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, list, циклы, список, beautiful-soup

```
def main():
    url = 'http://sample.ru'
    all_links = get_all_links(get_html(url))
    for i in all_links:
        print(i)
```

На выходе получаются дубликаты, так как одинаковые ссылки на странице (ссылка другая)
Хочу узнать как удалять такие

Comment: `all_links = set(all_links)`?

Comment: непонятный комментарий, хотелось бы наглядный пример без углубления в изучение python

Comment: Наглядный пример: `lst = ['aa','bb','aa','cc']; print(lst); print(set(lst))`

Comment: всё, вставил строку от MaxU - бинго! :D ...

Comment: или так: `all_links = set(get_all_links(get_html(url)))` ...

Comment: эммм...а можно как нибудь без рандомизации вывода?

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно сохранить исходный порядок, то можно воспользоваться [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
In [197]: lst = ['cc','dd','aa','bb','aa','cc','bb','dd','aa']

In [198]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [199]: new = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(lst))

In [200]: print(new)
['cc', 'dd', 'aa', 'bb']
```

или [вот так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17016257/5741205):

```
In [201]: seen = set()
     ...: new = [x for x in lst if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]

In [202]: new
Out[202]: ['cc', 'dd', 'aa', 'bb']
```